# Keychain Access Groups in entitlements for multi target iOS apps

Tags: ios, xcode, keychain, entitlements

I have an iOS application project with 2 separate `target`s. For example target A and target B. Now in `xCode8` when I turned `keychain sharing` to ON the Xcode generates two `A.entitlements` and `B.entitlements` files. Unexpectedly both of them have the same value like this:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)target1.bundle.identifier</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I mean in both of the file uses `bundle identifier` of my first target; and When I manually try to change the value for one of them the other one changes too.

As you know the Xcode will not sign the app while the value in `keychain-access-groups` exactly match the bundle identifier of the provisioning profile you use for sign.

So I am wondering how we can have two separate values for two separate entitlements files of two separate targets?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I finally fixed this by using below code in my entitlements:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Thanks Husein jaan for an elegant fix, you saved a lot of time of mine.

Comment: Yeah! You saved my time and made my day! Thank you for the useful information.